# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase'

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm using this piece of code I found on source code explorer to implement their fortnite command with my bot on discord. Upon running it, it says:

```
(node:11358) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
  at new User (/rbd/pnpm-volume/872a58d7-c703-412a-a641-c8df3e275a0a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/fortnite/4.1.1/node_modules/fortnite/src/User.js:13:73)
  at /rbd/pnpm-volume/872a58d7-c703-412a-a641-c8df3e275a0a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/fortnite/4.1.1/node_modules/fortnite/src/Client.js:61:24
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

(node:11358) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11358) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = require('fortnite');
const fortnite = new Client(`config.TRN_API_KEY`);

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  let username = args[0];
  let platform = args[1];

  if (!username) return message.channel.send("Please, provide a users nickname!(Fortnite)")
  if (!platform) return message.channel.send("Did you provide a platform ? Proper usage : ** ? fortnite < username > < platform > ** ")

  let data = fortnite.user(username, platform).then(data => {
    let stats = data.stats;
    let lifetime = stats.lifetime;

    let score = lifetime[6]['Score'];
    let mplayed = lifetime[7]['Matches Played'];
    let wins = lifetime[8]['Wins'];
    let winper = lifetime[9]['Win%'];
    let kills = lifetime[10]['Kills'];
    let kd = lifetime[11]['K/d'];
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("Lifetime Stats")
      .setAuthor(data.username)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .addField("Wins", wins, true)
      .addField("Kills", kills, true)
      .addField("Score", score, true)
      .addField("Matches Played", mplayed, true)
      .addField("Win%", winper, true)
      .addField("K/D", kd, true)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter("Requested By " + message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL);

    message.channel.send(embed);
  }).catch((err) => {
    message.channel.send('User not found!');
    console.error(err);
  });
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "fortnite"
}
```

I'm really just trying to figure out what the issue is. My gut says it's an issue with user.js but I could be wrong. All I know is that it's not working when I'd like it to. This is a command script that I got from Source Code Explorer and just wanted to try it out for myself but keep getting that `.toLowerCase` error. As you can see it's not even defined in this script. What should I do?

This is the code for the user.js script:

```
const Mode = require('./Mode');
const Stat = require('./Stat');

/** Class representing a full user */
class User {
  /**
   * @param {Object} data All of the data resolved from the API
   */
  constructor(data) {
    this.id = data.accountId;
    this.username = data.epicUserHandle;
    this.platform = data.platformNameLong;
    this.url = `https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/${data.platformName.toLowerCase()}/${this.username}`;
    this.stats = {};

    for (const mode in data.stats) {
      // Replace the playlist id with its name for the keys
      this.stats[modes[mode]] = new Mode(data.stats[mode]);
    }

    // TODO: Make lifetime single objects and not an array
    // Will be updated in a newer version
    this.stats.lifetime = data.lifeTimeStats.map(stat => new Stat(stat));
  }
}

const modes = {
  p2: 'solo',
  p10: 'duo',
  p9: 'squad',
  curr_p2: 'current_solo',
  curr_p10: 'current_duo',
  curr_p9: 'current_squad'
};

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186001/discussion-on-question-by-dewayne-redding-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's an update and fix to my question. They ended up sending me an email saying they've fixed some issues on their end and to regenerate a token and try again. Code working flawlessly. Thanks everyone for your help and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the .toLowerCase is, but judging by the fact is said property I will tell you if you wrote .toLowerCase it is wrong. toLowerCase is a function, not a property. Whenever you do .toLowerCase() <-- see parentheses? That is how any function is defined. But you were using a class, so I assume you know that too

Comment: Should have marked it as solved years ago but yeah, it was on their end. Their script was messed up not mine. Thanks though, I guess.